# Как лучше организовать архитектуру классов?

Tags: php, mysql

В проекте реализована модель MVC.
Сейчас задача стоит в написании класса, который бы определял текущий индекс языка на сайте`(_RU, _EN)` для реализации мультиязычности.

Мультиязычность в моем случае реализована по принципу выбора страна и подгрузки массива слов по установленному индексу, скажем _RU.

Т.е. в базе данных, во многих таблицах есть колонки, отличные только индексом, например:

```
CountryName_RU, CountryName_EN
```

Информация, соответственно, в них на разных языках.

Вопрос вот в чем: лучше написать класс, расширяющий классы моделей, чтобы при составлении запроса подставлялся индекс для конкретного поля, или же просто отдельную библиотеку класс, который реализовать в модели или конкретном методе модели?

Comment: Лучше всего использовать что-то наподобия [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) ))))

А если у вас будет 20 языков? БД может не выдержать - даже если использовать TEXT, некоторые записи вы сохранить не сможете.

Язык (локаль) - это проблема вьюхи, а не класса (тем более модели).

Comment: @BOPOH, вьехе тексты из базы на лету переводить?

Comment: @dimka3210, почему из базы? Что-то не понял, я про gettext говорю. И да - из вьюхи на лету, пока никто не жаловался. )

Comment: В БД сейчас хранятся не все языки(слова), в основном в базе названия категорий на разных языках, статические страницы сайта. А о модели я сказал потому что при выборке полей я могу указать конкретное поле с учетом языкового индекса.

Comment: Лучше не пытаться искать серебряную пулю в структуре классов. Уже двадцать пятый вопрос про "как мне сделать это через классы", и двадцать пятый же упирается в неверную архитектуру. Классы вообще дело десятое, они реализует интерфейс, который могут реализовать и функции, и пункции, и что угодно. Важны компоненты и их взаимосвязь.

Comment: Хорошо - тогда как бы вы сделали это? Неудобства в том, что текста есть и в helpers и library и View в Codeigniter

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, я бы на вашем месте все-таки посмотрел в сторону gettext`a - это будет явно быстрее и удобнее, чем через базу.

И как вы текст выводите? Прямо в helper`e через echo? Это что за MVC такое? Обычно сообщения (или ошибки) выводят в шаблонах, тогда с тем же gettext проблем не возникает - оборачиваете вывод во что-то типа `$this->localize($this->errors())` и у вас будет уже локализованный текст (конечно, если вы добавили локализацию для данного сообщения).

К тому же большинство шаблонизоторов/фреймворков явно поддерживают локализацию через него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если следовать тому, что уже есть, можно сделать промежуточный абстрактный класс модели для таблиц, в которых несколько языков `MultiLanguageModel` например, и в нем определить методы, по хорошему `getText()` для поля `text`, но если лениво это делать, то:

```
function __get($field)
{
    if(!empty($this->result->$field))
        return $this->result->$field;

    $lang = /*определяем как-то язык, например _RU*/
    $fieldLang = $field . $lang
    if(isset($this->result->$fieldLang ))
        return $this->result->$fieldLang;

    throw new ModelFieldException('Поле ' . $field . ' не найдено');
}
```

Comment: Для больших текстов накладно будет их из базы доставать (особенно при join`ах, особенно когда база расположена не локально).

Поэтому (если все-таки использовать базу) лучше сразу получать из базы только то, что требуется (в данном случае сразу получать требуемую локаль)